# euserv-register-service error/bug? Euca 4.4.4 on CentOS 7.5

Tags: eucalyptus

I have a fresh install of Euca 4.4.4 following the manual install procedure NOT the fast-start.  I've successfully initiated the cloud and am trying to register UFS with the CLC, which is on the same server/localhost.  Registration fails with a python error about proxies.  Registering any other services fails in the same way.  Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on or should I file a bug report?  Thanks!

```
[root@cloud ~]# cat /etc/centos-release

CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)



[root@cloud ~]# eval `clcadmin-assume-system-credentials`

[root@cloud ~]# euserv-register-service -t user-api -h 10.0.0.2 --debugger ufs-10.0.0.2

2018-10-03 14:16:29,503 DEBUG   RegisterService parsed arguments from CLI: {'Name': 'ufs-10.0.0.2', 'security_token': None, 'url': None, 'region': None, 'Partition': None, 'Host': '10.0.0.2', 'key_id': None, 'secret_key': None, 'Type': 'user-api', 'Port': None}

2018-10-03 14:16:29,503 INFO    Config finding global option default-region

2018-10-03 14:16:29,503 INFO    Config   novalue for default-region

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 INFO    Config finding global option max-retries

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 INFO    Config   novalue for max-retries

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 INFO    Config finding global option timeout

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 INFO    Config   novalue for timeout

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth using auth info from environment

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 INFO    RegisterService parameters: {'Host': '10.0.0.2', 'Version': 'eucalyptus', 'Name': 'ufs-10.0.0.2', 'Action': 'RegisterService', 'Type': 'user-api', 'Port': '8773'}

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 DEBUG   RegisterService sending flattened parameters as form data

2018-10-03 14:16:29,504 INFO    Bootstrap sending request (attempt 1 of 3)

2018-10-03 14:16:29,505 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth payload hash: [redacted]

2018-10-03 14:16:29,505 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth scope: 20181003/undefined-9965/bootstrap/aws4_request

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth canonical URI: /services/Empyrean

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth canonical query: 

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth canonical headers: ['accept:*/*', 'accept-encoding:gzip, deflate', 'content-length:97', 'content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'host:127.0.0.1:8773', 'x-amz-content-sha256:[redacted]', 'x-amz-date:20181003T181629Z']

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth signed headers: accept;accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth canonical request: 'POST\n/services/Empyrean\n\naccept:*/*\naccept-encoding:gzip, deflate\ncontent-length:97\ncontent-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nhost:127.0.0.1:8773\nx-amz-content-sha256:[redacted]v\nx-amz-date:20181003T181629Z\n\naccept;accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\n67cd38537793ad3c591fbf02b2e3593b8627af7e40de522d3495c25def205b5d'

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth string to sign: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20181003T181629Z\n20181003/undefined-9965/bootstrap/aws4_request\[redacted]'

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth signature: e88432a8cc7211bb1f2cced52fd6e0b6e11cf80d733053b028da6b1d2c4147c2

2018-10-03 14:16:29,506 DEBUG   HmacV4Auth signed headers: accept;accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  method: POST

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  url:    http://127.0.0.1:8773/services/Empyrean

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: Accept: */*

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=[redacted]/20181003/undefined-9965/bootstrap/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=[redacted]

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: Connection: keep-alive

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: Content-Length: 97

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: Host: 127.0.0.1:8773

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: User-Agent: eucalyptus-admin/4.4.4 (CPython 2.7.5; Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64; x86_64) requestbuilder/0.7.1 requests/2.14.2

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: X-Amz-Content-SHA256: [redacted]

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  header: X-Amz-Date: 20181003T181629Z

2018-10-03 14:16:29,507 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  data:   Action: RegisterService

2018-10-03 14:16:29,508 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  data:   Host: 10.0.0.2

2018-10-03 14:16:29,508 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  data:   Name: ufs-10.0.0.2

2018-10-03 14:16:29,508 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  data:   Port: 8773

2018-10-03 14:16:29,508 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  data:   Type: user-api

2018-10-03 14:16:29,508 DEBUG   Bootstrap request  data:   Version: eucalyptus

euserv-register-service: error: get_environ_proxies() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requestbuilder/service.py(177)send_request()


-> proxies = requests.utils.get_environ_proxies(url)
```

@sjones:  Thanks.  Interesting.  I built from a plain CentOS7 Everything ISO but with Minimal Install only installing packages exactly as described in the Euca Install docs.  Looks like my version of python-requests came from here? and the Everyting ISO is the culprit:

[root@cloud ~]# yum provides python-requests
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.den.host-engine.com
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.iweb.com
 * extras: centos.servint.com
 * updates: centos.den.host-engine.com
python-requests-2.6.0-1.el7_1.noarch : HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings
Repo        : base

python2-requests-2.14.2-1.el7.noarch : HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings
Repo        : centos-openstack-queens
Matched from:
Provides    : python-requests = 2.14.2-1.el7

python2-requests-2.14.2-1.el7.noarch : HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings
Repo        : @centos-openstack-queens
Matched from:
Provides    : python-requests = 2.14.2-1.el7

So I'll rework my installation but start by disabling all of these extra repos and re-installing packages from the base repo only.  Hopefully they aren't needed anywhere else by the Euca Install:

[root@cloud yum.repos.d]# ls
CentOS-Base.repo           CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-OpenStack-queens.repo  CentOS-Storage-common.repo  epel.repo          eucalyptus.repo
CentOS-Ceph-Luminous.repo  CentOS-fasttrack.repo  CentOS-QEMU-EV.repo           CentOS-Vault.repo           epel-testing.repo  midonet.repo
CentOS-CR.repo             CentOS-Media.repo      CentOS-Sources.repo           datastax.repo               euca2ools.repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have requests 2.14.2 installed, but this version:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/python-requests-2.6.0-1.el7_1.noarch.rpm

is expected for CentOS 7.5.

Comment: Thanks.  Per my edit I'm going to rebuild my environment from the minimal iso and not just the minimal install of the everything iso.  Its possible I've got bad/unsupported versions from these extra repos at other points in my install procedure.